# Is there a way to have tika stop parsing a file once a match is found?

Tags: java, apache-tika

I have a Java 8 program that walks the directory tree from a user-supplied node, searching for files that match a list of user-supplied filename patterns.

The list of matched files can be filtered with an optional user-supplied `String` to find. The code checks for this string using the **end result** of parsing. This is really bad when huge files are found along the tree walk.

But it's bad anyway. As soon as the string to find is found, we're wasting time parsing the rest of the file.

Is there a way to have tika stop parsing a file once a match is found?

*EDIT*

The code that the program is based on:

```
package org.apache.tika.example;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.mime.MimeTypeException;
import org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class ParsingExample {

  public static boolean contains(File file, String s) throws MalformedURLException, 
                     IOException, MimeTypeException, SAXException, TikaException
  {
    InputStream         stream    = new FileInputStream(file);
    AutoDetectParser    parser    = new AutoDetectParser();
    BodyContentHandler  handler   = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
    Metadata            metadata  = new Metadata();
    try
    {
      parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata);
      return handler.toString().toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase());
    }
    catch (IOException | SAXException | TikaException e)
    {
      System.out.println(file + ": " + e + "\n");
      return false;
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      try 
      {
        System.out.println("File " + filename + " contains <" + searchString + "> : " + contains(new File(filename), searchString));
      } 
      catch (IOException | SAXException | TikaException ex) 
      {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
      }
  }   

  static String parseExample = ":(";
  static String searchString = "test";
  static String filename = "test.doc";
}
```

`Parser.parser` returns all the text in the file for `BodyContentHandler` `handler`. There's no loop available to the implementer of a parser. None that I'm aware of; hence the question.

*EDIT 2*

What I really want to know, I guess, is whether there's a tika method that only reads `n` characters from a file instead of all. Then I could maybe stick a loop around it and exit if search string is found.

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: Have your code set a flag which terminates the loop? Throw an Exception?

Comment: Please refer to *EDIT* in OQ.

Comment: Did you try reading the [JavaDocs for BodyContentHandler](http://tika.apache.org/1.9/api/org/apache/tika/sax/BodyContentHandler.html#BodyContentHandler%28int%29)? You seem to have opted to explicitly disabled the write limit on it, but now are asking how to turn it back on again...

Comment: JavaDocs isn't installed. I tried three things: include tika-parsers-1.9-javadoc.jar as a library, right-click tika-app-1.9.jar and select `Add JavaDoc` (which brings up the 1.10 web page with nothing obvious to download--bunch of files not ending in .jar), and right-click a method, which simply says javadoc not found, but once gave option to add Javadoc; also failed. But whether I specify a write limit or not, there's still no loop that I can determine to exit from when I find the string.

Comment: I also tried this: change Project Properties | Libraries | Edit compile-time library tika | select Javadoc tab and add path to the javadoc file mentioned in previous comment. Still no javadoc found.

Comment: If there was a way to have tika give me the file's SIZE, that might help, but I still need a way to have it parse inside a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can move query matching part into your own `ContentHandler` implementation (you can take `DefaultHandler` as base) with reassembling text from parts passed to `ContentHander#characters(char[],int,int)` and abort parsing by throwing exception there after match found.

It's definitely not a pretty solution but it should stop parsing.

**UPD** code sample:

```
public class InterruptableParsingExample {
    private Tika tika = new Tika(); // for default autodetect parser

    public boolean findInFile(String query, File file) {
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        InterruptingContentHandler handler = new InterruptingContentHandler(query);
        ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
        context.set(Parser.class, tika.getParser());

        try (InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {
            tika.getParser().parse(is, handler, metadata, context);
        } catch (QueryMatchedException e) {
            return true;
        } catch (SAXException | TikaException | IOException e) {
            // something went wrong with parsing...
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
}

class QueryMatchedException extends SAXException {}

class InterruptingContentHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    private String query;
    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    InterruptingContentHandler(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        sb.append(new String(ch, start, length).toLowerCase());

        if (sb.toString().contains(query))
            throw new QueryMatchedException(); // interrupt parsing by throwing SaxException

        if (sb.length() > 2 * query.length())
            sb.delete(0, sb.length() - query.length()); // keep tail with query.length() chars
    }
}
```

**UPD2** Added to tika-example package: https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/trunk/tika-example/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/example/InterruptableParsingExample.java

Comment: @Konstantin--I appreciate the Answer but I'd need more details about how and where to adjust code. This is my first venture into Tika and parsing and I've faked it (pretty well) so far.

Comment: @DSlomer64, updated answer with code example. Control flow is inverted (normal flow contains throwing exception) but similar pattern is used in Tika's `WriteOutContentHandler`.